# Unable to determine volume version and state. CHKDSK aborted

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive

I can not access my external harddisk. When I plug my HDD in my computer the OS tells me "Do you want to format?" It seems that its partition table has deleted.

I test it by `CHKDSK /F` and I got this error :

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.
The first NTFS boot sector is unreadable or corrupt.
Reading second NTFS boot sector instead.
Unable to determine volume version and state.  CHKDSK aborted.
```

How can solve my problem without wiping my data.

Comment: The partition table is fine else Checkdisk would not be able to tell you that the filesystem is NTFS. It is the information inside the NTFS volume which has been corrupted. Normally the fastest way to recover would be to reformat the volume and then restore the content from a backup. IF you have no backup and the data is important then **do not change anything on the disk. Do not let anything write to it**. First make a full disk backup using tools such as ddrescue.

Comment: @Hennes my data on this disk is very important I can not format that? do you have another idea?

Comment: @Hennes Is ddrescue for Linux? how can find this software for windows?

Comment: ddrecue runs under LInux (or BSD, or OS/X), but this does not prevent you from using it to make a copy of a HDD which is used for windows. E.g. see [this first it on Google](http://www.bootmed.com/using-ddrescue-for-windows-machines/).  There are also plenty of other tools for making a full disk image. E.g. Symantec ghost (with the right options marked), plain old `dd` (works the same as long as there are not hardware errors. Maybe even windows on ImageX, though I have no experience with the latter.  Regardless of the tools used, the goal is a full disk backup before writing anything.

Comment: my drive in Disk Management is RAW and it tells that it 's not formatted, with this situation can I rescue my data?

Comment: @Hennes Can you help me about which right option that I should to select?

Comment: Can you add the output of [start] [run] `diskpart`, `list disk`, `select disk #` (replace the # with the number of your broken disk), `list partition` to the post ?

Comment: -`Partition ### -Type   Size  Offset
------------- ---------------- ------  -------
-Partition 1 Parimary  465 GB  31KB`